# Drools - Sliding window not working as expected

Tags: drools

I'm new to drools.  I've defined the following rule to add the last two numbers in the stream together.  I then send in a stream of 100 events, with the values set from 1 to 100.  So I would expect the output to be 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 etc.

```
declare TestEvent
     @role( event )
     value : int
end
rule "Simple Rule"
when
    $sum : Integer() from accumulate ( TestEvent( $value : value ) over window:length( 2 ); sum( $value)  )
then
    System.out.println("Value: " + $sum );
end
```

The session is started using "fireUntilHalt" in a separate thread. If I put a delay of 10 milliseconds between every event inserted it works as expected.  However when I don't have the delay, the results aren't as expected.  Usually it just prints 0 and 197.  Sometimes I might get a number or two in-between as well.

Why does this happen and what I should do to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally understand it.
Having `fireUntilHalt` running in a separate thread means that the rules are only evaluated every now and then (not sure what that time period is).  My assumption was that they would be evaluated on every `insert`. So on every `insert` the accumulator values are updated, but the rules evaluated aren't evaluated. So because my rules are inserted quickly (in about one second), the first and last insert is all that seems to be evaluated.

To get this to work so every insert is evaluated, I removed the `fireUntilHalt`, and did a separate `fireAllRules` after each insert.

Answer (score 0):

Sliding windows are a crutch. Replace it by simple logic.

```
class Pred {
   Integer pred;
}

rule procInt1
when
  $p: Pred( pred == null )
  $i: Integer()
then
  modify( $p ){ setPred( $i ); }
end

rule procInt
when
  $p: Pred( $i1: pred != null )
  $i2: Integer()
then
  System.out.println( $i1 + $i2 );
  modify( $p ){ setPred( $i2 ); }
end
```

The fact that you have two threads doesn't mean that you can't have race conditions. The thread inserting events isn't suspended and so everything is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  What I'm after though is trying to understand sliding windows (and their limitations).  Currently I'm none the wiser why I'm getting the results I am. If the results depend upon the speed events are fired into the stream then they seem very flawed. Any ideas why I get the behaviour I'm seeing?  How are these rules evaluated internally.

Comment: Anything the Drools engine can do is subject to Java's thread scheduling. If you cram in 5 events in a single task and ask for the last two: what do you expect?

Comment: i had expected the rules to be evaluated with each insertion. This is clearly not the case, therefore isn't fireUntilHalt very unsafe as it could be possible that not all rules would fire correctly as events are replaced?

Comment: Oh yes indeed, LHSs are evaluated with each insertion - but that doesn't mean that rules fire. - In a realistic scenario, events don't result from loops, they arrive via some i/o interface and that will cause thread rescheduling. But asking for the "last 2" means that you'll get the last two, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks it is getting clearer.  So I'm trying to understand the limitations. So if I had a scenario of needing to detect if three events in a sequence were going in an upward trend, then isn't it possible that if a stream of events was fired in very fast I would miss this using fireUntilHalt, as the values in the accumulate are being replaced with the latest events fired in?

Answer (score 0):

Time related rules rely on 'time'. Smallest time tick for drools seems to be 1ms. Rules will be evaluated on each insertion (and respective consequences will be added to the agenda) but agenda will be executed on next millisecond tick (or when you explicitly fire all rules).